# Set up Firebase admin sdk with proxy (Java)

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to use firebase to authenticate my users via Google. On my Java server I'm verifying the validity of the idToken and every time I get this error:

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Error while verifying token signature.
```

I identified the problem as being the proxy of my server that avoid the http requests made by the sdk. I tested my code on my computer and it works so I'm pretty sure the problem is the proxy.

Here is my code:

```
InputStream serviceAccount = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(<fileName>);

Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(<address>, <port>));
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport.Builder().setProxy(proxy).build();

HttpTransportFactory httpTransportFactory = () -> httpTransport;

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
   .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount, httpTransportFactory))
   .setDatabaseUrl(<adress>)
   .setHttpTransport(httpTransport)
   .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdTokenAsync(<token>).get();
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a bug. As you can see [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/auth/internal/FirebaseTokenVerifier.java#L53), the token verifier does not use the HTTP transport injected through options. I'd appreciate if you can create an issue for this on GitHub.

In the meantime, you might be able to get around this limitation by configuring the HTTP/S proxy for the JVM. Try setting the `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort` system properties when starting the JVM (more details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)).

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem, and still waiting for a greater solution.

In the meantime, I've decompiled the WebSocket class (com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket), and created an underlying socket by myself, then droped this decompiled class in a new package in my project: com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.

The creation of the SSLSocket is around the line 295 of this class.

I've created the socket this way:

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

InetSocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress("200.5.92.169", 8080);
Socket underlying = new Socket(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxyAddr));
underlying.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
SSLSocket sslSocket  = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(underlying, host, port, true);
```

Comment: Seems like workaround! Could you please add some clarification about this approach: have you manually imported all needed classes from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/tree/master/firebase-database/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/database/tubesock (tubesock repo) or maybe found some more clever workaround? I'm asking this because custom `WebSocket` class needs plenty of dependecies from firebase tubesock package.

Comment: Just decompile the WebSocket class, create a package named 'com.google.firebase.database.tubesock' in your project, and put your fresh decomipiled WebSocket class in there. Next, you have to modifify the code block that I'd mentioned. Take care about the firebase-admin version. I've it working with version 5.2.0, I tried to upgrade to more recent versions but this approach stopped working, because the related classes had changed so much.

Comment: Thanks a lot, already solved the issue another way on server side. Yup, the only working versions might be few till 5.2.0.

Comment: @kkaun: Could you please check this post and help me if you can? I have simmilar problem with FCM. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272413/how-to-configure-proxy-server-usage-for-weblogic-12c

Comment: @zappee, I assume that the post was removed by its author before I checked your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found your mistake. You are missing one method of FirebaseOptions.Builder, which:

**.setHttpTransport(transport)**

the code should be like this:

```
         NetHttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport.Builder()
             .setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyProps.getHost(), proxyProps.getPort())))
             .build();

         FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
             .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream, () -> transport))
             .setHttpTransport(transport)
             .build();
         
         FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```